# How do I upload multiple images to an imgur album from command line?

Tags: bash, curl, sed, imgur

This is what I have now, it works on a single image.

```
curl -vH "Authorization: Client-ID 3e7a4deb7ac67da" -F image=@/path/to/image https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml
```

to get the result open in your browser, I have

```
curl -vH "Authorization: Client-ID 3e7a4deb7ac67da" -F image=@/path/to/image https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml | grep -Eo '<[a-z_]+>http[^<]+'|sed 's/^<.\|_./\U&/g;s/_/ /;s/<.*>//' | sed  's/^.*imgur\.com\//http:\/\/imgur.com\//g;s/\.[^.]*$//' | xargs xdg-open
```

but how can I upload multiple images to an anonymous album ?

I knew I can create an album with

```
curl -vH "Authorization: Client-ID 3e7a4deb7ac67da" -F "title=imgur"  https://api.imgur.com/3/album
```

Then I guess I need to make some curl calls on each and every one of my images to add them to the album one by one? Or There is some magic command that I can do all of these in just one curl call? (create the album, upload multiple images, and get the album link back)

Imgur [image upload api](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image) says there is a `album` key, but I don't know how to pass it with curl.(I can see the deletehash from the result of last album creation call.)

The ultimate goal is to add some menu to kde dolphin browser( as servicemenu ) Single image upload is already working.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I hope you've not put the personal credentials in question. ;)

Comment: I thought it was a publicly shared client id?

Comment: I see ! You're good then.

Answer (score 1):

[find](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm) command is your friend.

Suppose you wish to upload all the `.png` images you could do the below stuff.

```
find /path/to/images/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f  -name "*.png"  \
     -print0 | while read -rd '' filename
do
curl -vH "Authorization: Client-ID 3e7a4deb7ac67da" \
     -F image=@"$filename" https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml
done
```

Comment: Thanks! but how could I create an album and add all the images to that album?

Comment: Sorry pal ! There should be workaround for that too.,but I think I should stop at this point.